# How should I load a different submenu in a template (submenu depends on page)?

Tags: wordpress

So this is the basic template page code:

```
<?php

/*
 *  Template name: About Content Template
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); the_post(); ?>

<div id="container">
        <div id="main-content" class="dropShadow roundEdge">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'About Submenu', 'menu_id'  => 'submenu',  'container' => 'false' )); ?>
             <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar();?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

For simplicity, let's say that the only thing that changes is the menu name, depending on the page group. The page groups are e.g. `About` and `Products`. The first thing that comes to mind is to add a custom field to each page that belongs to a group and set a property `"category=About"` or `"category=Products"`. In the functions.php I would have an array of category names mapped to the menu name, e.g. `"About = About Menu"`, so before loading the menu, I'd get the custom property, read the menu name value from the array and set it as an argument to the `wp_nav_menu` function. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is relatively simple. The first page in the submenu (eg. History when you press About) can be viewed as the category main page, so I took all the other pages that are linked in the submenu and put the first page (History) as their parent. Then I created a submenu through the dashboard and called it History submenu. The code that makes this work is simple:

```
<?php $submenuName = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
        $submenuName = $submenuName . " Submenu";
        wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => $submenuName, 'menu_id'  => 'submenu',  'container' => 'false' ));
```

get_the_title gets either the parent page name or, if there's no parent, the page name. Though not much different than using custom fields, I think it's more elegant sin

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a custom field, you may use the [is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) function to determine which sub-menu to apply. If your sub-menu names are in sync with categories, this can work in an automatic manner.